# Is it acceptable to copy tag wiki from Stack Overflow to equivalent tag wiki on other Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, attribution

I would like to update the wiki for [f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23) on the Programmers and Computer Science sites. I think just copying the content of the wiki from Stack Overflow would be fine since it's relevant on each of those sites.

Is it okay for me to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All content is licensed under the [Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), including tag wikis.

That means you can copy tag wiki text across verbatim, provided you give attribution. Tag wikis are collaborative efforts and no author information is publicly displayed, reducing the attribution requirements somewhat.

Personally, I think it is fine to put the attribution in that case into the edit summary; link to the original tag wiki in that note to indicate where you copied it from. The edit history of the tag wiki from there on out will document what was copied and what was changed.

Shog added attribution in tag wikis he copied with a footnote; see the [bug tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info) for an example. The format in raw Markdown is:

```
<sub>Copied from: http://[original sitename]/tags/[original tag]/info</sub>
```

Comment: FWIW, I copied a *lot* of tag wikis from MSE to MSO when we split them apart - [here's an example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info) of how I added attribution. Note that I did this even in cases where I was the primary author of both wikis, because it allows interested readers to identify contributing authors as well.

Comment: This example is really useful, thank You.

Comment: @Shog9: thanks, I like the `sub` footnote format; added to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. If you're not the original author of the content on SO, you need to cite the source when you make a derivative of it elsewhere.
2. Chances are you shouldn't just directly copy and paste - you could start with the SO content, but customize it to fit the target site.